# How to not display elements with CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive website and basically I don't want to show some elements of the document on large and medium devices. But when it comes to small devices,they should appear..

So I have set the class name of **secondary** for these two menu items that should NOT be appear on medium and large devices:

```
<li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks secondary"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
<li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks secondary"><a href="#">Link</a></li>`
```

I think the main idea behind this is fine but the problem is it does not even work! I mean those two links still appear in medium screens!!

So how can I fix this issue?

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .secondary {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .secondary {
    display: inline;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav id="nav_wrapper" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="BKoodakBold leftlinks"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user ico"></span></a></li>
        <li class="BKoodakBold leftlinks"><a href="#" onclick="toggleNavPanel('sections_panel')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search ico"></span></a></li>
        <div id="sections_panel">
          <div>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
              <input type="submit" class="search BKoodakBold" value="جستجو"></input>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks secondary"><a href="#">ورود/ثبت نام</a></li>
        <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks secondary"><a href="#">جستجو در گویانت</a></li>
        <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#">درباره ما &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign ico"></span></a></li>
        <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#">ارشیو ویدیوها &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-gift ico"></span></a></li>
        <li class="BKoodakBold rightlinks"><a href="#">صفحه اصلی &nbsp; <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe ico"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-center">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="assets/img/logo.png" width="50"></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order of you CSS?  If the width of the screen is exactly 767 pixels, it will always display (unlikely to be your cause, but possible).

Comment: Well, the snippet you pasted seems to work correctly. First link disappears on bigger screens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bootstrap 4 having responsive utility class [Please refer the link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/)

If you are using the Bootstrap 3 also such utility class [please refer the link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 1):

looks like you use bootstrap. so have look at this link.

**https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/** (for V4 Alpha)
**http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities** (for v3.x)

you dont need to add extra classes. just use these

may be you need `.hidden-md-up` class

Answer (score 0):

Check below code added in your html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and change your @media screen code.

```
@media screen and ( max-width: 550px){
.secondary{
display:none;
}
}
```

This one here means if your display is smaller then 550px it will not display.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide a band of "middle width" to not have any.

If you need to select a "middle" width, then combine those two into one and use that to hide the desired element.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 850px){
  .object {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

If your medium device is defined as that range, this would make the element with the .object class not be visible in the middle range.